# No android target and com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli (cordova build android)

Tags: java, android, cordova

```
cordova requirements android
```

result:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 10.0.2
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli
Gradle: installed C:\Gradle\bin\gradle
Some of requirements check failed
```

No android target and com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli

```
cordova build android
```

Error code

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 10.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

I have Android Studio installed and Gradle manually

[image: Variables]
[image: PATH]

Comment: Please show the system PATH setting.

Comment: @greybeard I've already inserted

Comment: So, what is that `JAVA_HOME   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14` doing in the System Variables? Hm. Strange. What is the output of `java -showversion` in a command window?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_171"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
after uninstall Android Studio and Install Android Studio 2.3.3 all works fine. After updating to the latest version, everything still works
I also had to uninstall JDK 10.0.2